# HTTPS Post via Axios throwing error Client network socket disconnected/EPROTO

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, axios

I am using axios to post form data to an https server. However I am constantly thrown off with either of the two errors

1. error in response:Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
2. Error: write EPROTO 21068:error:14094438:
   SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 80

The following is my code

```
axios({
method: "post",
timeout: 50000,
url: "https://******",
data: form,
headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          'Authorization':
                                              "Basic " +
                                              new Buffer(
                                                  properties.get("username") +
                                                  ":" +
                                                  properties.get("password")
                                              ).toString("base64")
             },
```

})

If I use http instead of https, it works happily. But I am not sure if that is the ideal solution. Any pointers would be helpful!

Comment: you manage the backend server? can u make sure your backend is running correctly? What can u see from the network inspection panel?

Comment: in the server console trace I get either Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established or EPROTO error

Comment: The backend seems to be running ok.. Is it some TLS version mismatch between server and client.

Comment: most of the time if this kind of thing happen, it's server side issue. Probably your apache/nginx settings. *seems to be running ok* doesn't mean it's okay, you probably need to ask your guys to check it out.

Comment: I have this webapp made using node js hosted on Azure which is trying to post some data using Axios on an https server. I will try to get some logs from the server guys.

Comment: what do u mean? so it's server to server?

Comment: yes it is from a server to a server

Comment: does your communicating server have https enabled?

Comment: My web server is https enabled in azure

Comment: if your axios is working with http, but not https, means your server is probably not configured properly with https

Comment: you mean in azure?

Comment: the url to my web service is secured and has https in it? Doesnt that mean https is enabled? or is it something different?

Comment: Actuallly I always use this https server to post data, this is the only time I am trying to send a file as form data and the error comes.